Ссылки, отправляющие сообщение Telebot
Пишу телеграм-бота на Python с помощью Telebot.
Хочу реализовать такую функцию, что в сообщении присутствуют пронумерованные inline-ссылки, при нажатии на которые, бот получает информацию о ссылке, на которую пользователь нажал. Например, ссылка может вызывать отправку боту сообщения с номером ссылки, или сразу напрямую передать через API, что пользователь нажал на ссылку номер x.
Можно ли реализовать это средствами Telebot, есть ли какие-то внешние модули для подобной задачи?

Если имеется ввиду URL-кнопки, то насколько мне не изменяет память их нажатие отследить нельзя. Разве что ссылка будет вести на ваш собственный сайт, и уже на нём  обработать переход через дополнительные метки в самом url‍♀️

@Amgarak Вы абсолютно правы, нельзя получить callback от кнопки, которая прямо ведёт на какой-то сайт.
